# How to take the average of each indexes length

Tags: python, list

I got a list that I need to take the average of each index. So for example:

```
lst = ['ABC','DEF','GHIJ']
```

index 1 has a length of 3, index 2 is a length of 3 and index 3 is a length of 4. The average or mean of this would be roughly 3.33 (3+3+4/3 = 3.33)

I tried this so far but for some reason am stumped on how to iterate through this correctly:

```
lst = ['ABC','DEF','GHIJ']

for avg in range(len(lst)):
    length = len(lst[avg])
    sums = sum(a) // len(lst)
```

Which returns an error. I tried switching sum around but still getting errors.

How can I fix this? Sorry if this is a trivial fix but I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `sum(len(x) for x in lst) / len(lst)`

Comment: @StephenRauch You beat me by one second! :)

Comment: @Tomothy32, except I was too lazy to build an answer...

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
lst = ['ABC','DEF','GHIJ']

avg = sum(len(s) for s in lst) / len(lst)
```

It basically takes the sum of the generator expression `len(s) for s in lst` and divides it by the length of the list. Another option with `map`:

```
avg = sum(map(len,lst)) / len(lst)
```

Comment: Slightly faster/shorter (for sufficiently long inputs anyway) would be `sum(map(len, lst)) / len(lst)`, but only because `len` is a built-in implemented in C (if it wasn't, `map` would be a pessimization).

Comment: I had tried the second implementation but had no luck when I was attempting this on my own before. Thanks for the help though man (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
sum(map(len,lst))/len(lst)
3.3333333333333335
```

Another way

```
len(''.join(lst))/len(lst)
3.3333333333333335
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed your answer when I made my edit. Take my upvote!

Comment: @Tomothy32 no worry man :-) I adding another way make my answer still unique here :-),

Comment: Without actually timing it, I would suppose the second would be slower...

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: lst = ['ABC','DEF','GHIJ']

In [3]: sum([len(i) for i in lst])/len(lst)
Out[3]: 3.3333333333333335
```

Comment: the `[]` in the sum are unneeded

Comment: Didn't know that. Good to know!